# Showing that some term of a sequence is 0

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence defined thus : I start with $x_1 = n$. Then $x_{k}$ is defined by first writing $x_{k-1}$ in terms of base $k$ expansion, i.e. $$x_{k-1} = a_o+a_1k+a_2k^2+\cdots$$ and then reading it in base $k+1$ and finally subtracting 1 i.e. $$x_k = a_0 +a_1(k+1) +a_2(k+1)^2 +\cdots -1.$$ I need to show that I can find an $N$ for which $x_N=0$.

I am interested in hints or suggestions for approaching the problem and not the solution.

I checked out the sequence for some values of $n =1,2,3,4,5$ and see that the trend before 0 is hit is the appearance of consecutive numbers $3,2,1$. For $n =4$, the sequence seems to be $4,8,7,7,\cdots,6,5,\cdots,0$ and for $n=5$, it reads $5,9,15,17,19,21,23,24,25,26,25,24,23,\cdots, 22,\cdots 0$.

So the sequence increases and slowly peters out decreasing to hit 0.  I see that eventually $k$ soon overtakes the $x_k$ value at some point and that is when the decreasing trend is seen. But I am not sure how this helps.

Comment: Well, if $$k \geq x_k \geq 0,$$ then your base $k+1$ expansion of $x_k$ has only one digit: $x_k = a_0$ (and this structure persists in subsequent terms!).

Comment: @GoodBoy You mean after some k?? which is true, but how do I reason that out?

Comment: On reflection, I think another viewpoint is desirable: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed my mind. Considering $n$ to be non-negative (it doesn't work otherwise!), 
this viewpoint might be helpful.

Collecting the coefficients ($a_j$'s), you can naturally represent each point in the sequence $(x_k)_{k \geq 2}$ as an integer tuple in $\mathbb Z^{N+1}$, where $N$ is the largest power of 2 which appears in the binary expansion of $n$.

$$x_k = \sum_{j=0}^N a_jk^j \quad\longleftrightarrow\quad y_k = (a_0,\ldots, a_N),$$

where the $a_j$ are all understood to be non-negative. The length doesn't need to change, so you can deduce what you need from the corresponding sequence $(y_k)_{k = 2}^\infty \subset \mathbb Z^{N+1}$.

In particular, the corresponding rule for obtaining $y_{k+1}$ from $y_k$ is quite simple (I invite you to think about it):

> $$ y_k = (a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_N) \longmapsto y_{k+1} = (a_0 - 1, a_1, \ldots, a_N),$$
>  
>  where, whenever you see a $-1$ in any entry, you should replace this with a
>  $k$ and subtract one from the next entry along: e.g. if $k = 9$, $(-1,1) = (9,0)$
>  which corresponds to $10 - 1 = 9$, so that the $a_k$'s are all non-negative.

and so once you've figured that out/peeked, it should be hopefully much clearer why you at some point obtain $x_k = 0$ in your sequence—a.k.a. $y_k = (0,0,\ldots, 0)$.

Comment: Thank you. I will think about what you said and then get back to you. Hopefully, I wont have to peek :)

Comment: Ok, what I see is that in that $(N+1)$ tuple, each entry from the right eventually is 0 and finally the $a_0$ entries also become 0 and that term is $0$. So the idea is that starting from the rightmost entry, we make each entry 0 and so on. Am I right?? But I am still struggling to mould into a precise argument. Thanks a lot though!! This is really neat.

Comment: Sounds good to me. It'll be a wordy one for sure. It may help that each of the $a_j$'s are initially ones or zeros